# bash script can't find source file in script running in systemd

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, startup, systemd

I have set up a systemd.service that starts a bash script when the system boots. The script starts, but it seems that it cannot find the referenced source files but when i start the same script from the terminal i works fine. Al scripts are in one and the same directory.

Anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

systemd.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=RIB
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/release/.scripts/start-script.sh start
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

part of the start-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source config.sh
source function.sh


check_connection #function

# GET LOCATION IN .JSON FILE
get_location #function
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    printf "%s\n""Can't get location\n\n"
else
    printf "%s\n""Location successfully retrieved\n\n"
fi
```

source config.sh:

```
version="2021.01.25"
date=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
time=`date '+%H:%M:%S'`
temp_path="/home/$USER/temp"
release_path="/home/$USER/release"
info_path="$release_path/to/info"
content_path="$release_path/to/content"
ftp_url="ftp.test.com"
```

source function.sh:

```
function check_connection ()
{
    printf "%s\n""${Green}Check connection with $ftp_url.${Color_Off}\n\n"
    while ! timeout 0.2 ping -c 1 -n $ftp_url &> /dev/null
    do
    printf "%s\n""${Green}RIB cannot reach $ftp_url, check WIFI connection.${Color_Off}\n\n"
    sleep 5
    done
    printf "%s\n""${Green}RIB can reach $ftp_url.${Color_Off}\n\n"
}
```

Comment: `printf "%s\n"".` - why is there no space? Didn't you mean `printf "%s\n" "..."`? `it seems that it cannot find the referenced source files` "it seems"? From where? Do you have an error message? `Anyone have any suggestions to fix this?` What do you think __current working directory__ of the script is when run from systemd?

Comment: Use full paths when referencing the source scripts

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding `WorkingDirectory=/home/user/release/.scripts/` to your `systemd.service` file. This sets the working directory for executed processes.

Comment: Your `get_location` function isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: BTW, re: `function`, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: ...and it would do a lot of good, wrt. giving you enough information to solve this yourself, to put `set -x` above the `source` lines so you can read a trace of what the actual values being assigned are.

Comment: Thank you very much! i am still in a bash scripting learning curve. `printf "%s\n"".` without a space in the script it works but with the space it doesn't.
I did not post the full source here so it is correct that he get_location function is not defined in the code here. sorry for this confusion but I didn't want to post unnecessary code but only give the idea. @CharlesDuffy do you mean that its better to use `NAME() COMPOUND-CMD or function NAME { CMDS; }` instead of `function NAME() COMPOUND-CMD`?

Comment: "works" is not very clear, but `printf` treats its first argument as a format string, and subsequent arguments as values to substitute into that format string. If you put _everything_ in that first format string, that gives you very different and usually-undesirable behavior .

Comment: @Coen17st, and yes, I mean it's better to use `NAME() COMPOUND-CMD`, as the link above describes ("better" in the sense that your code will be compatible with more shells).

Comment: Anyhow -- `printf '%s\n' 'Can't get location' ''` is the more common way to write one line `Can't get location` and a second blank line after it. One can also just do `printf $'Can\'t get location\n\n'` or `printf 'Can'"'"'t get location\n\n'` or what-have-you, but I don't really see a point to the extra complexity. Putting everything in one string that contains a `%s` but then not providing a value to fill in that `%s` placeholder is **definitely** wrong, in the sense that bash doesn't guarantee what it'll do, so your code could stop working entirely in a future version.

Comment: @Coen17st, ...btw, for the future -- an ideal code example is a [mre]; it should be the shortest possible thing that causes your error when run without changes, but that does mean it needs to be tested to _cause the exact same error when run without changes_. So things that are unrelated to the error should be taken out -- but then the code needs to be tested to _actually still cause the same error_ even without them, before the question is posted. `get_location: command not found` is, after all, not the same error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy! i haved changed the printf code and in the future i will post minimal code as descriped in the link.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is adding `WorkingDirectory=/home/user/release/.scripts/` to the service file.